# \varnothing 'undefined control sequence'

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I am using `amsmath` and all of my math symbols are appearing using `$ $` block but `\varnothing` is undefined. `\emptyset` [image] works but its symbol is a bit different than `\varnothing` [image]

Note: images taken from LaTeX wikibook.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to load the `amssymb` package.