# Getting errors by using \diameter from the amssymb package in an equation

Tags: equations, errors, amssymb

I want to add the diameter symbol, as described there [Diameter on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter#Diameter_symbol) in my equation:

```
begin{equation} 
\diameter~Aufwand~in~\% = \frac{\diameter~Aufwand~in~ZE~f"ur~die~Testt"atigkeit}{\diameter~Aufwand~in~ZE~f"ur~die~Entwicklung} 
\label{equ:Durchschnittlicher-Aufwand}
\end{equation} \par
```

Therefore i used the packages as desribed there [usepackage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14304/varnothing-undefined-control-sequence)

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
```

3 times I got an error like this:

```
! undefined control sequence
l.XX \diameter
```

Can you give me some hints, what I should change or what can be the problem? I have no idea...

Comment: Use the package ```wasysym```.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As also noted [by Tanvir in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551353/getting-errors-by-using-diameter-from-the-amssymb-package-in-an-equation#comment1392420_551353), the `wasysym` package defines the `\diameter` command. In order to use this command, you have to load the package.

In th following small example, I have also corrected the text inside of the equation. Instead of manually adding spaces, you should place the text inside of `\text{...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym} % for the diameter command 
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
\text{\diameter\ Aufwand in \%} = \frac{\text{\diameter\ Aufwand in ZE für die Testtätigkeit} }{\text{\diameter\ Aufwand für die Entwicklung}} 
\label{equ:Durchschnittlicher-Aufwand}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use `\diameter` inside `\text`. It's not really a math symbol, because it's defined as `\mbox{\wasyfamily\char 31}`, so `\text{\diameter\ Aufwand...}`

Comment: @egreg: Good point. I have changed my answer accordingly.