# How can I draw a bold diameter symbol?

Tags: symbols, bold, boldsymbol

I am trying to draw a bold diameter symbol.

I imported the diameter symbol by the package `wasysym`as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551355/260914) and looked at several ways how to use bold math symbols as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297253/norm-symbol-have-different-sizes-in-equation) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols), yet none of them seemed to work for me.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If possible, can you show the required symbol as image format?

Comment: The symbols provided by `wasysym` are not math symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not show what you tried or what error you got, but wasy is available in bold

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym} % for the diameter command 
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
\text{\diameter} \neq \textbf{\diameter}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I included that I tried the linked answers and in most cases it is not bold with no extra error, but you are right I could have done a better job on this! Using your example just gives me no bold diameter symbol

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime my example produces the image shown, with a bold ⌀