# \varnothing no different from \emptyset

Tags: amssymb

I don't understand why \varnothing looks exactly the same than \emptyset in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}

\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}


\begin{document}
    \[x\in\emptyset\]
    
    \[x\in\varnothing\]
\end{document}
```

Here is what I get:
[image]

Yet, I load the package \amssymb.

Comment: amssmb is almost completely over-written by unicode-math by design

Comment: $x \in \emptyset$ sounds like contradiction.

Answer (score 8):

Add

```
\show\emptyset
\show\varnothing
```

and you see

```
> \emptyset=\protected macro:
->\varnothing .
l.12 \show\emptyset
                 
? 
> \varnothing=the character ∅.
l.13 \show\varnothing
                   
?
```

so `\varnothing` is the direct Unicode mapping and `\emptyset` is an alias  to that.

You can use diameter U+2300 as the round form

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}

\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\show\emptyset
\show\varnothing
    \[x\in\emptyset\]
    
    \[x\in\varnothing\]

    \[x \in ∅︀\]

    \[x \in ⌀\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @David. But how can I obtain the "rounded version" of \varnothing (the one we see in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14304/varnothing-undefined-control-sequence)

Comment: Unicode declined to consider the slashed 0 and slashed circle forms as distinct so mapped both to U+2205 you see same in HTML where `&empty;`, `&emptyset;`, `&emptyv;`, `&varnothing;`  _all_ map to ∅ which is round or not depending on the font.

Comment: https://unicode.org/L2/L2015/15268-slashed-zero.pdf @Didier

Comment: @Didier that was accepted so in theory later unicode U+2205 U+FE00 is slashed zero but not supported by lua/xe latex (variant selectors are tricky) test your browser:  ∅︀  or ∅

Comment: added Unicode 9 (2016) https://www.unicode.org/Public/9.0.0/ucd/StandardizedVariants.txt

Comment: Thank you @David. Before using LuaLaTeX, I used PdfLaTeX and \varnothing was rounded like in Bourbaki (like in the pdf you mentioned). So I will read this pdf and try to obtain this rounded version. But I have doubts: if I understand you correctly (not sure about that because I am French), it depends on the font and maybe with modern Latin font, I won’t get it. Maybe with a \RenewDocumentCommand{\varnothing} and changing font, I Could get it?

Comment: @Didier I'm looking, or you could probably use diameter U+2300 ⌀ , but you do not have to use unicode-math if you prefer the ams fonts. You can use amssmb with luatex I added an example

Comment: Thank you again @David. I like Unicode math because I can add French math style. And I use Latin modern Font (even though I find the characters too thin) because it uses rounded x and y in math mode (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689860/rounded-y-in-unicode-fonts?noredirect=1#comment1712169_689860)

Comment: I type \AtBeginDocument{\RenewDocumentCommand{\varnothing}{}{⌀}} and it works fine